# Localized shadow below object with shadow catcher in cycles

Tags: rendering, transparency, shadowcatcher

I am trying to set up a shadow capture for an object with a diffuse yet localized shadow using world lighting and transparent background.
The problem is that the shadow bleeds out too far from the object and creates an undesirable crop line at the edge of the boundary (see red arrow).
By looking at the alpha channel it seems that there are two parts of the shadow: the part right under the cube (which I want to keep) and the more diffuse part, indicated by the green arrow (which I want to remove).

[image: Current bad result.]

**What I want** is the following, which I have created using photo editing.

[image: Desired result]

I would like to avoid messing with the compositor or creating any specialty textures. Are there any world, render, material, object (or other) settings that I can adjust to create this effect?

**For reference: here are the steps to reproduce the undesirable figure:**

1. Default Blender 4.0.2 configuration
2. Switch to cycles
3. Set film to transparent
4. Remove default lamp
5. Set color of world to white (#FFFFFF) and transparent. Leave strength at 1.0
6. Add a plane, make large enough to fill all of camera view, then move slightly below the default cube.
7. For plane: Object -> Visibility -> Enable Shadow Catcher
8. For plane: Object -> Shading -> Shadow Terminator -> Shading offset=1.0

Comment: The softness of the shadow is given by the diffuse lighting of the white world around it, which is (kind of) infinitively large. The size of the light source determines the size and spread of the shadow. If a gigantic hemisphere around the object creates a too soft shadow, you need another light source of which you can control the size and location and therefore softness and direction of shadow better. Or increase the brightness of the world until the very faint shadows are no longer visible. Or change location or focal length of the camera so it captures everything.